# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl

I have the following code:

```
    public void checkFeatureUnlock()
    {
        final String player = Minecraft.getInstance().player.getStringUUID();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try (final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault())
            {
                final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://ldtteam-auth.chatchain.co/api/minecraft/" + player + "/features");
                final InputStream responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity().getContent();

                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseBody));

                String inputLine;
                final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                isFeatureUnlocked.set(Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString()));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

This works fine for all users (windows + linux). However, one of our users, constantly gets:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The server has a valid "Lets Encrypt" certificate (which works fine for all other users too) and the user that gets the exception has

"[15:29:15] [main/INFO]: Added Lets Encrypt root certificates as additional trust"

In the log.

Comment: Perhaps they are using a particularly old version of Java that doesn't have the Lets Encrypt root in the cacerts file.

Comment: I thought so too, I had them update and it was still happening.

Comment: A totally wrong system date can also make certificate validation impossible (if the time is outside of the validity period of one of the certificates in the chain).